# syntax error at or near TO (ROLLBACK TO SAVEPOINT)

Tags: postgresql, transaction, rollback, savepoint

The following sql is a part from a FUNCTION ,i want to rollback to rbk SAVEPOINT :

```sql
  for ptrEnt in entite loop
      -- positionnement du point de retour pour une entitÃƒÂ©
    savepoint rbk;
      -- purge de la table des redevances de l''entite
    test := pckg_activ.initredevanceentite(ptrEnt.cod_ent);
      -- calcul de la redevance
      test := pckg_activ.calculredevanceentite(ptrEnt.cod_ent);
    -- controle calcul de la bonne execution pour l''entitÃƒÂ©
    if (test = 0) then
        -- initialisation des departements associes a une entite
        test := pckg_activ.initdepartement(ptrEnt.cod_ent);
      -- validation des modifications
      commit;
      -- generation de l''etat recapitulatif
      test := pckg_activ.recapentitegestionnaire(ptrEnt.cod_ent,ficHisto);
    else
        rollback TO SAVEPOINT rbk;
      report := jour + 7;
      update sav_rdv_date
          set date_dem = report
          where cod_ent = ptrEnt.cod_ent;
        RAISE NOTICE '!!erreur de patrimoine => abandon du traitement pour cette entite';
      commit;
    end if;
  end loop;
```

**entite** is a cursor that has been declared and the **for loop** is in a *BEGIN* bloc.

I get the error ERROR:  `syntax error at or near "TO"`. I think that the syntax is correct , it it related to the cursor ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use transaction management statements in PostgreSQL functions.

[Limited support for that was added in procedures](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-transactions.html), introduced in v11.

But you can (implicitly) use savepoints by using an `EXCEPTION` clause in a block.

So instead of

```
LOOP
   SAVEPOINT a;

   /* something */

   IF /* something else */ THEN
      ROLLBACK TO SAVEPOINT a;
      /* still more */
   END IF;
END LOOP;
```

you should use

```
LOOP
   BEGIN
      /* something */

      IF /* something else */ THEN
         RAISE EXCEPTION 'catchme';
      END IF;
   EXCEPTION
      WHEN raise_exception THEN
         /* still more */
   END;
END LOOP;
```

Comment: i've been digging around documentation for information on the "limited support [for transaction management statemtns] in v11" but not finding anything... do you have any details about that which can share?

Comment: I have added a link to the documentation.